# 3rd party software for money transfer within the app

Tags: ios, apple, appstore, in-app-purchases, webmoney

Я писал apple о том , что бы они мне дали разрешение на использование сторонних сервисов для банковский переводов. А то они берут 30% и это не выгодно...

На это они мне ответили:

"Hello Bojan,

Thank you for your email.

I understand your interest in using a 3rd party software for money transfer within the app, but we do only allow the use of certified Apple technology, not only for its compatibility, but for obvious privacy reasons.

If you have specific questions on this topic, you may also contact our App Review team.

Also, I would suggest you to visit this page: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Please let us know if you have any questions or need any further assistance. We're happy to help.

Alessandro
Apple Inc. "

Может мне кто нибудь сказать, пример какой причины должен быть, что бы они разрешили сторонние переводы?
Что они именно хотят услышать ?

В моем приложении человек кладет деньги, что бы другой выполнил какое нибудь задание... 
Если не выполняет то деньги возвращаются... Но если будет возвращаться на 30% меньше + ждать ему нужно период когда я сам выведу эти деньги из itunes connect, то на это соглашаться  никто не будет.

Или даже если выполнил задание тот или иной человек, он не будет желать долго ждать, что бы ему перечислили деньги так еще на 30% меньше...

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не имеет отношения к программированию

Comment: Вдруг кто то знает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кратко, у Apple такие правила: все виртуальные и/или цифровые товары и/или услуги должны быть оплачены через App Store. В других случаях приложение будет не пропущено/удалено.

Если Вы докажете, что оплата не попадает под эти правила, то можете подключать что захотите.